# how to create a method to display sales order id on basis of field selection in purchase order? sale order reference is already integrated in purchase

Tags: odoo

I have added a sales order reference in a purchase order form. I have also added one custom field in both sales and purchase forms. The field is "Trader name". I need the sale order reference field in the purchase order to display the sale order ID on the selection based on Trader Name.

I am selecting Trader Name while creating the sale order, and I want the sale order reference in the purchase order form to display the same sales order ID's linked with specific a Trader Name.

Example:

1. Sales order form-->trader name = abc--->so#200
2. purchase form--->selecting trader name "abc" and sale order reference field should automatically display all the sales order # under the selected Trader Name

NOTE: Trader Name field already fetched to purchase order form

on the basis of selected sales order id, it should also fetch the same order lines from sales order form

the code is in odoo 11

Here is my code:

***purchase_views.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<record id="purchase_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">purchase.order.form.inherit</field>
<field name="model">purchase.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<field name="partner_ref" position="after">
<field name="x_trader_name"/>
<field name="sale_order_id"/>

 </field>
 </field>
```

***purchase.py**

```
from odoo import models, fields

    class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'
    sale_order_id = fields.Many2one(
    'sale.order',
    "Sale Order",
    help="Reference to Sale Order",
    )
    </record>
    </odoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter your sale orders.

Add [onchange](https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html#api-onchange) method for `trader name` and fetch all related sale ordes then change the domain of `sale_order_id` to show only needed records.

You should return:

```
{'domain':{'sale_order_id':[('id','in',SO_IDS)]}}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the Onchange method, i am new to Odoo and a bit confused